# Is there a free way to convert DGN v8i to... any other format?

Tags: convert, dgn, free-software

(Update: We have postgis and ogr2ogr (etc.) but not any ESRI or Microstation software.)

I just got DGN v8i files and I can't find any **free** way to convert them to... anything else.

[FME](http://www.safe.com/fme/fme-technology/) and [AutoDWG](http://autodwg.com/dgn-to-dwg/) are not free.

[OpenDGNViewer (aka DGNDirect)](http://opendesign.com/files/guestdownloads/OpenDGNViewer.zip) appears to be able to view but not export.

I really would be happy with any other format:

- DGN v7
- SHP
- DWG
- ?

Crazy how difficult it seems to be to work with what is apparently a standard in many municipalities.

Comment: What software do you have available now?  Do you use ArcGIS, or open source software like QGIS?  What do you want to do with the files, what is your end use?  Having information like this will make it easier for people to give you a work-around strategy.

Comment: http://autodwg.com/dgn-to-dwg/

Comment: Almost a duplicate question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32489/how-to-convert-from-dgn-to-shp-or-dwg-files

Comment: While it may be used in many municipalities, that does not mean that it is an open format.  The municipalities that use it, expect that the contractors that work with them, will have this software as well.  For all that many people want every file format to be freely readable, it is still ultimately the choice of the software developer.  If they haven't released the source, it will remain closed and you will have to find a converter, like @Mapperz linked to.  They likely have to charge because they paid a fee, need to recoup costs, and/or may be required to contractually with Bentley.