# Open version 8 DGN file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, dgn, microstation

I want to open my version 8 Microstation DGN file with QGIS without any loss of information. Please, do you know an extension supported by QGIS to do this job?

Comment: you might want to check out the answers to [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/32489/55203) to see if any of the answers is suitable? There seem to be several options.

Comment: I guess the problem you are having centres on GDAL/OGR support for DGN files (only versions predating 8.0 supported).

Answer (score 2):

You have to save your file as dgn V7 and open as a vector layer. You won't lose any information.