# Converting from DGN v7 to shapefile by GRASS plugin

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, convert, dgn

I read two comments in several topics about conversion from DGN files  to Esri shapefile

Both of these comments are interesting for me, but I seek to have them explained in more detail.

I have DGN file v7. I would like to convert it to ESRsri shapefile to work on QGIS with all attributes.

I tried to use the GRASS plugin, but it does not support DGN file to load into this, so how can I do that as someone said in his comment

[image]

First comment:

> v7 is the most current .DGN support. Have you tried loading it into QGIS and exporting it from QGIS? You can do this by right clicking on the .DGN file and choosing Save As, but again, only up to .DGN v7

How can I find save as on the file? I did not understand this point.

Second comment:

> I have been wanting to do the same thing, with the same issues. I have successful imported my DGN files into QGIS using the GRASS plugin. I used the v.in.ogr tool in Grass. It allows you to bring DGN files in as lines, points and polys.

Link :[Converting from dgn to shp or dwg files using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32489/converting-from-dgn-to-shp-or-dwg-files-using-qgis)

[image]

i could not find not v.in.ogr

Comment: Where did you read these comments?  If they are still there please provide links to them or at least to the post(s) that they are on.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32489/converting-from-dgn-to-shp-or-dwg-files-using-qgis

Answer (score 1):

You cannot open directly a DGN file in GRASS GIS. You can import it, but before you have to create a location (see: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/helptext.html) with the EPSG code (projection) of your DGN. You may create a new mapset also (beside the PERNAMENT).
After these steps start your GRASS session. You will see two windows. In the Layer Manager window select File/Import vector data/Import common vector formats [v.in.ogr] from the menu and select your DGN file and set the name of output vector map.

Depending on what you would like to do with those data, I suppose QGIS is an easier option to import DGN data (see: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html). From the point of view of QGIS DGN files are similar to DWG/DXF files.

Comment: where can i download data base of grass ,bcs iam not able to find  the directory on my lap.frst step in ur link ,location of directory

Comment: You can use an empty folder on your machine for grass database. When you get the grass startup window, press Browse button to select the database directory. The usual name for dis folder is "grassdata".

Comment: i created grassdata folder but it said to me no grass location found,choose different grass database directory,so what should i do .could u explain example all steps.thanks

Comment: Please press the new button left to the Select GRASS Location list. It starts a wizard. You should be familiar with locations and mapsets to use GRASS.

Comment: I am scratching my head at your last paragraph. DGN is a different file format than DWG/DXF, created by a different company. Also, QGIS's DWG/DXF Import feature only imports **.gpkg** files.

Comment: Yes DGN and DWG/DXF are different formats but logically very-very similar, both are CAD formats. The same entity types, layer logic, etc. If you import them into QGIS the result will be the same.